# Backbone JS where to put Application main logic

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications, backbone.js

Using Backbone i'm starting to build an App where i have everything cleanly separated. But now i have the following question. Where should i put the App main logic, in the views or in the model.
For example i have a view and a model, which are binded to a button and when i click that button i have to make

```
$.ajax(params)
```

do i put that in the view or the view calls a method with :

```
this.model.doAction(params)
```

which do you think is the best approach?

Comment: Depends on what sort of things `$.ajax(params)` is doing I suppose.

Comment: An ajax request then i have to process the response, it involves both changes in the view and in the model

Comment: Probably should be in the model, then events from the model would trigger changes in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an `events` property in the view which is of the format `{"event selector": "callback"}` for eg. `{"click .collapse": "collapse"}` where collapse would be a function defined as a property of the view. Then write your ajax request code in this callback function.

Also, unless I am missing something, "binding a view and model to a button" doesn't sound correct Backbone way to me. Instead you should think of one instance of model associated with one instance of the view. Whenever an attribute of the the model instance changes, a model `change` event will be triggered. You can bind a view function to this event so that change in the model is reflected in the view. Here is a quick example

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
   // ...
});

var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        // here, make changes to the dom as per changes in model
    }
});
```

To associate a model with a view instance, you can pass the it while instantiating a new
view object..

```
var book = new Book({
   title: "A great book"       
});

var view = new BookView({model: book});

view.model.set('author', 'AGreatAuthor');
```

The set function call will fire change event and will result in render function of view 
to be called.

Refer to the [annotated source of Todos](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html) app example for a complete example.